# How to add a module to a bin directory?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I currently have a project structure like this:

```
/components/my_component/src/main.rs
                            /module.rs
```

if I change this to add a `bin` directory

```
/components/my_component/src/bin/main.rs
                                /module.rs
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0601]: `main` function not found in crate `my_module`
   --> my_component/src/bin/my_module.rs:568:2
    |
568 | }
    |  ^ consider adding a `main` function to `my_component/src/bin/my_module.rs`
```

Cargo appears to think everything inside `bin` is a binary. This makes sense, but then how do I use modules with this style of directory layout?

Comment: This might be a bug. `cargo clean` followed by `cargo build` seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: ... now it's shown up again ?

Answer (score 4):

Create a directory `my_binary` under `bin`, and put `main.rs` and `module.rs` under it. Then `main.rs` will be able to declare `mod module;`.